# SQL sum total value by id from different tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to show total earnings for each employee but my query shows sum of all earnings for one employee

[Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Pyu.png)

[Payments Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrB3C.png)

Here is my query

```
SELECT Employee.FirstName , Employee.LastName, SUM(Payments.Value) AS Total_Value
FROM Payments, Employee
WHERE Employee.Employee_ID = Payments.Employee_ID
ORDER BY Employee.Employee_ID
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DujE.png)

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @forpas but I've to display name, surname and earning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be generating an error, because it is an aggregation query that has no `group by` and has unaggregated columns.

Unfortunately, you are using a database (or version thereof) that does not generate an error.  But you just need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, SUM(p.Value) AS Total_Value
FROM Payments p JOIN
     Employee e
     ON e.Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID
GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Employee_ID
ORDER BY e.Employee_ID;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- If you want to sort by the employee id, then include that in the `GROUP BY` as well.  That also handles the situation where different employees might have the same name.